# AudioQueueGetProperty(queueObject, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, &status, &statusSize) returning garbage for status

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

Just came across a problem while updating an existing app to iOS 6.

in my sound.h file

```
AudioQueueGetProperty(queueObject, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, &status, &statusSize);
```

sets status to some garbage value for iOS6.

I have an iPod on which when run this function yields status to be either 0 or 1.

For iOS 6 I'm using simulator and Xcode 4.5 beta 4.

Comment: Make sure you upgrade your Xcode and iOS SDK to the latest release versions - both are out of beta.

Comment: Show some more code. What is statusSize set to before the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got that handled. I initialized statusSize using AudioQueueGetPropertySize(...) . It initializes statusSize to the right value. That was previously hard-set to 32 that was causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. If you're using a 'bool' for 'status', try changing it to 'int'.

Not sure what they did to break it, but this seems to fix it - for me anyway.

Comment: Got that handled. I initialized statusSize using AudioQueueGetProperty Size(...) which i was initializing my self earlier.